# Resolving a warning in macro

Tags: c, macros, gcc-warning

I am dealing with a few macros producing warnings. One of them is `ConvToSector(x)`:

```
#define STARTSECTOR 0x0002000u
#define STARTLSB    6u
#define STARTNUM    7u
#define TRICKYLSB   3u
#define ConvToSector(x) (((x)>=STARTSECTOR) ? ((((x)-STARTSECTOR) >> STARTLSB) + STARTNUM) : ((x) >> TRICKYLSB))
```

producing

```
conversion to 'uint8_t' from 'long unsigned int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

I know all of the constants are unsigned and input to ConvToSector(*x*) is unsigned integer (uint32_t). So where is `long unsigned int` coming from?

Comment: Are you assigning the return value to `uint8_t`? What is `sizeof(unsigned long)` and `sizeof(unsigned)` on your system?

Comment: What are you storing the result into?

Comment: Please give a *complete* self-containing example. This includes the call to ConvToSector and the types for the parameter and the variable where you store the result.

Comment: @Kevin, this exactly was the problem, i.e. the variable in which result was stored was of type `uint8_t`. This should be obvious to a seasoned engineer but for a junior gcc makes it harder since it is referring macro as source of the warning instead of the macro occurrance itself in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is correct; converting a `long unsigned int` value to `uint8_t` can alter its value.

You can inhibit the warning either by not specifying the `-Wconversion` option (it's not enabled by default so something must be setting it), or by using a cast rather than an implicit conversion. I can't tell exactly where the cast should be added without more information.

As for the `long unsigned int` type mentioned in the message, again, it's hard to tell without seeing more code. It's likely that `uint32_t` is a typedef for `unsigned long int` -- but a quick experiment shows that gcc's error messages refer to the declared type even if it's a typedef.